# How do you get a short pulse out of a sustained high?

Tags: capacitor, pulse

I am trying to get a half-second pulse out of a long/permanent high pulse. I am still new to electronics and think a capacitor would be involved?

I want to use CMOS logic level.
Accuracy is not too much of a problem, it is only going to be used to activate a monostable.
The voltage I am working with is 15V.

[image: logic graph]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, but your question is missing all sorts of details and needs a major edit to avoid being closed for lack of detail. (1) Your timing diagram has no trigger for the pulse. How is the pulse supposed to know when to turn on? (2) You have no voltage or current requirement. Is this TTL or CMOS logic level? (3) What accuracy do you require?

Comment: What power supplies are you using? Is the input signal also the supply to the detector circuit, or are they separate? 15 V is pretty large, is it actually just a digital signal, or do you care what happens at, say, 10V? Will the input ever be low, and how should the output respond in that case?

Comment: If the first trace is permanently on it is irrelevant as it carries no information. You need to draw the trigger pulse, edge or level change and show its duration if it's a pulse. What is driving the trigger? What is the monostable configuration? (A schematic would be useful.)

Comment: In a sustained high, how do you know when to produce the pulse? Or did you mean a  rising edge? (the event at the very start of a "high".)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to use this circuit to activate a monostable, but I believe the circuit you're looking for actually *is* a non-retriggerable monostable. It outputs a fixed duration pulse on a rising edge (or falling, depending on the circuit), look at the second picture in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostable). Would it be possible to operate the monostable that you want to activate in a non-retriggerable mode?